# Shopify-.liquid file: how can I add a js validation (with onsubmit which I have) to exist form?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api

Here is the form tag which I want to add validation to:

{% form 'customer_address', customer.new_address %}

```
<div>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'customer.addresses.add' | t }}" />
</div>
```

{% endform %}

Comment: Which type of validation default HTML5 or JavaScript based?

Answer (score 1):

The **{% form 'customer_address', customer.new_address %}** return an HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="/account/addresses" id="address_form_new" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

so you could use the id **#address_form_new** or the action attribute: **[action="/account/addresses"]**

```
$('#address_form_new').on('submit', function(e) {
// Your validation
});
```